Playwright parallel and sequential running of tests simultaneously
I have two kind of tests:enter image description here
And I would like to run the tests in the SerialTests folder using only one worker (first serial1Tests then serial2Tests sequentially). The other tests (in the ParallelTests folder) will be run in parallel.
For example:
If I specified 3 workers, then 2 workers would run all the tests from ParallelTests and 1 worker would run the tests from SerialTests. Is it possible to do it this way?
I tried to do it this way:
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  testMatch: /.*Tests\.ts/,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 1 : 0,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    viewport: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080
    },
  },
  workers: 3,

  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Google Chrome - Parallel',
      testDir: "./tests/ParallelTests",
      fullyParallel: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Google Chrome - Serial',
      testDir: "./tests/SerialTests",
      fullyParallel: false,
    },
  ],
});

But then it runs serial1Tests and serial2Tests in parallel

Please check this document : https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel
In this doc there is section called "Serial mode"
you can mention your describe as serial. It won't run parallel with test cases. But two different describe will run parallel.

I imported all tests in one file and run this file serially.
More information:playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
